# How can I modify this javascript so it'll remove both <b> and <i> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I'm trying to create the rough equivalent of the "**removeFormat**" command for Safari.

Right now I can modify this to remove the bold or italic tags applied to text, but not both at once.

```
function RemoveElement (element) 
{
   while (element.firstChild) 
   {
      element.parentNode.insertBefore (element.firstChild, element); 
   }
   element.parentNode.removeChild (element);
}

function RemoveBold () 
{
    var boldTag = document.getElementsByTagName ("b");
    var italicTag = document.getElementsByTagName ("i");

    for (var i = 0; i < boldTag.length; i++) 
    {
        var boldTags = boldTag[i]; 
    }

    for (var a = 0; a < italicTag.length; a++) 
    {
        var italicTags = italicTag[a];
    }
    if (boldTag||italicTag)   
    {
        RemoveElement (italicTags, boldTags);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have messed up your loops:

- `boldTag` and `italicTag` are [live NodeLists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList)
- After the loops, the variables `boldTags` and `italicTags` contain the last item of the respective lists (or are still undefined)
- Then, you check for existance of the two NodeLists...
- And call the `RemoveElement` function with two arguments, while it has only one parameter.

Just use this:

```
var boldTags = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
var italicTags = document.getElementsByTagName("i");
while (boldTags.length) // it's *live*
    removeElement(boldTags[0]);
while (italicTags.length) // it's *live*
    removeElement(italicTags[0]);
```

Comment: I tried doing something almost exactly like this before and it didn't work. Just to be sure, I tried this code and...nothing. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or not telling you enough. I put the above code in a function and used the onclick event in a button to trigger it.

Comment: I'm using functions such as the following to change the font in editable <pre>'s:    SetToBold () {document.execCommand ('bold', false, null);}

Comment: Thank you for your points. I'm mostly aware of them, but I gave up after trying to solve them. I tried giving RemoveElement two arguments instead of the one I have listed, but that failed. I also tried duplicating RemoveElement and giving it a different name, but that failed as well. Basically, I'm able to remove both Italic and Bold tags when the correct tag has been already applied, but not when they're independent of one another.

Comment: No, the point is to call it multiple times :-) Also, note that I have named my function lowercase - do you get any errors in the console or does only nothing happen?

Comment: No, I hadn't noted the capitalization change. :) After I changed it to uppercase it worked. In the meantime I found some other code that worked...albeit very slowly in Firefox. Anyway, another day of learning something new. Although what I did try before was quite similar, I don't think I had [0] at the end. I'm such a noob scripter, lol. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: How can I make it so the text stays selected?

Comment: Selections? Um, good question. I'm not so familiar with that parts of JS, but I suggest you'd need to cache the Range object and reapply it if it was lost...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just dynamically modify the styling for the bold tag? That would be more true to the example you're trying to emulate.

In other words:

```
$('b').css('font-weight', 'normal');
```

Comment: You can change the selector to match your specific needs, mine is just selecting all the bold tags on the page.

Comment: When using the Safari Web Inspector I noticed that it applies <b> and <i> tags. I tried using the following, but it didn't work:   element.style.setProperty("font-weight","normal");

Comment: Is `element.style.fontWeight = 'normal';` any better?

Comment: Nope. :(  Css-based attempts at changing it haven't worked at all so far, so I've been focusing on removing the html tags. I tried "removeProperty" too.

Comment: Interesting... That's a shame. I guess just keep going with your current plan. I'm curious why that would be though.

Comment: Initially I was using the css-based approach, because I was using FF 13, and removeFormat didn't work until I upgraded to FF 14. So I know that there probably isn't anything wrong with the css coding. It also doesn't seem to be Safari, since it also doesn't work in IE or Opera, which also used html tags.